# What's the proper way to check if JSON has a key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, key

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this code that is supposed to parse JSON

```
my_object_id = my_object.key?("id") ? my_object['id'] : nil
```

But when the “my_object” JSON is ‘[“name", "Info”]’, I get the below error

```
undefined method `key?' for ["name", "Info"]:Array
```

What’s the proper way check if my JSON is going to have an “id” key?

Comment: `my_object.key?("id")` will give error because `my_object` is an array and `key?` is a method for hash.
Can you post the json structure of my_object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pramod indicates, it seems you're confusing hashes with arrays.

You could do something like this, meaning it would only try to retrieve an `id` when `my_object` is of the correct type:

`my_object_id = (my_object.is_a?(Hash) && my_object.key?("id")) ? my_object['id'] : nil`

However, this need for this conditional likely indicates a weakness elsewhere in your design, since you can't be sure of the type of `my_object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **has_key** method.

```
my_object_id = my_object.has_key?("id") ? my_object['id'] : nil
```

On the side note, you can always check the list of available methods for any object by running **object.methods** in console.

Comment: `key?` is an alias of `has_key?` so this should not make any difference.

Comment: Noted. Thanks :) I guess then actual solution depends on @Mike's json object.

Comment: The JSON is posted in the question, and also in the erorr message, which is "NoMethodError (undefined method `has_key?' for ["name", "Info"]:Array):".